# backbone.js + require.js + jsdoc3: Missing dependency issue with jsdoc

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jsdoc

I'm trying to document my modularized backbone application by using jsdoc3. However, I receive the error, "exception from uncaught JavaScript throw: Error: Missing dependency: Backbone.model" when I try to run this code through jsdoc:

```
    /**
    * A module representing a dog model
     * @module dogModel
     */

define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
    ], function(_, Backbone) {

    /**
    * @constructor
    * @requires Underscore
    * @requires Backbone
    * @extends Backbone.Model        
    */
        var dogModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
         //blah blah blah blah
        });

    return dogModel;
});
```

The error occurs when I add "@extends Backbone.Model." I would also welcome any suggestions on alternative patterns for documenting a backbone app (which uses require.js), using jsdoc3.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Do you receive the above error when you run the above code, or when you try to generate the documentation using jsdoc3?

Answer (score -3):

If you don't mind checking out an alternative documentation generator, you may well like [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/). I use it with Backbone + Require + Node.js. Works great!